# Likelihood of query volume to cause deadlocks and CPU overhead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, schema, relational-database, database-schema

We are having 2 problems with our database right now:

1. deadlocks
2. maxing out DB CPU

The most egregious characteristic I can see is that we are doing very simple tasks with a lot of queries/DMLs. Capturing a 1 or 2 strings now occupies 15 - 20 queries/DMLs. Capturing small-ish surveys with answers for 3 or so questions is spread out over 20 - 30 queries.

There's a lot of queries because (1) the code has changed hands a lot, (2) the schema is hyper-normalized because the entity framework tables can't really be adjusted without causing all kinds of problems, (3) legacy features are still being supported.

All of these operations hit one or more tables repeatedly during the same operation.

3 of our developers speculate reducing the number of these queries will reduce CPU overhead (?), but one of our developers thinks this will not help with our deadlock issues.

Right now our transactions are basically all set to SNAPSHOT isolation level (if that helps). I have just completed some analysis on adding indexes, but I haven't seen the results yet.

Will reducing the number of tables reduce deadlock problems?

Will reducing the number of tables/queries reduce DB CPU overhead?

Comment: 1) no. deadlocks have nothing to do with the number of tables. they have everything to do with HOW you're issuing your queries. 2) maybe/yes. fewer tables MAY make for more efficient execution plans and leveraging indexes. reducing the number of queries MAY reduce overhead, but sometimes multiple simple queries are far more efficient than bigger/complicated queries.

Comment: In terms of deadlocks, the number of queries performing similar operations may be of concern. If you have many queries performing update/delete/insert operations on one table, this could pose a problem. To reduce deadlocks, I'd look to consolidate queries performing the similar operations, then add indexing as appropriate to the underlying tables in the queries.